# Why does Tomcat 7 Memory usage looks like saw? (picture)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7

Why does Tomcat 7 Memory usage looks like saw? Souldn't it be more stable? Has it got something to do with the GC? And if yes, does it mean there is a "leak" that is present? By the way this server is a test server with nothing on it.

Thanks!

[Tomcat 7 memory Image link](http://s14.postimage.org/mnrm7t20v/tomcatsawp.png)

Blue is Used heap

Orange is Heap size

Comment: I think it is just cyclic garbage collector working.

Answer (score 3):

It's just the way the Java garbage collector works. It lets memory accumulate until it hits a certain threshold, then it runs the garbage collector and frees up what it can. So it's not that Tomcat's actually *using* more memory, just that Java hasn't bothered to free it up yet.

Comment: I'm guessing because most moderately-experienced programmers know about the garbage collector and the saw pattern, and one of them probably thought the answer to the question was too obvious for the question to have any value. But that's just my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

saw pattern is *very* normal.

even if app is doing nothing, there are background tasks that create garbages.